# Why do I have poor image quality on my Sony a99 at high iso?

Tags: post-processing, sony, high-iso

I've just purchased a Sony A99, the first version, and I'm disappointed to find the photos are very noisy at high ISO, even as low as 800 or 1000. Is this typical for this camera? Is there a way to process it out, or are all the high ISO settings just there as window dressing?

Comment: You need to post some examples. While there are post-processing methods to reduce noise, I wouldn't expect this to be a major issue at ISO 800?

Comment: That very much depends on your exposure. And the subject.  If you take very dark images at ISO 800 you are getting way more noise in the shadows than at 800 in a evenly lit scene. https://www.imaging-resource.com/PRODS/sony-a99/sony-a99HI_ISO_NR.HTM has some examples. Please also note that the MK1 is 10 years old and ISO capabilities do not hold up to current sensors.

Comment: So to answer, please post an example and the steps you did for post processing of the RAW files. If you use JPGs, there is a noise reduction setting in the camera I believe.

Comment: ISO does not cause noise. Low amounts of light cause noise.

Comment: Add a handful of examples of pictures you regard as too noisy. If possible, also tell us at which temperature they were made.